# no_sanitize not supported in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, clang, address-sanitizer

Does anyone know how to disable the address sanitizer for specific functions with the clang version shipped with Xcode 7.x? It seems the function attribute no_sanitize(..) is not supported or do I miss something?

```
__attribute__((no_sanitize("address")))
```

I use XCode 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81) based on LLVM 3.7.0.

http://llvm.org/releases/3.7.0/tools/clang/docs/AttributeReference.html#no-sanitize-clang-no-sanitize

Comment: I just checked and it's not there in the clang version that comes with Xcode 7.2 either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use `no_sanitize_address` instead, which appears to be supported in Apple's current version of clang (as of Xcode 7.2), e.g. the following compiles for me without any warnings:

```c
__attribute__((no_sanitize_address)) void foo(void)
{

}
```